# installation failed for deno in ubuntu wsl, zsh: command not found: deno

Tags: javascript, curl, deno

I am trying to install deno in ubuntu wsl by this
`curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh`

and then i am trying to check my installion by `deno --veraion`
but i am getting `zsh: command not found: deno`

I also tried reopening my terminal but it won't work either.

I did this:
`curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh`

`deno --version`

expecting:
`x.x`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Deno to your path in ~/.zshrc

The install script should have told you to manually add it to path, as seen in its code:

```
#part of install.sh
case $SHELL in
    /bin/zsh) shell_profile=".zshrc" ;;
    *) shell_profile=".bashrc" ;;
    esac
    echo "Manually add the directory to your \$HOME/$shell_profile (or similar)"
    echo "  export DENO_INSTALL=\"$deno_install\""
    echo "  export PATH=\"\$DENO_INSTALL/bin:\$PATH\""
    echo "Run '$exe --help' to get started"
```

Carefully look at the output of the install script. It should be telling you exactly what to add to your .zshrc file.

If the script does not output the variables that you need to add, try running the script with zsh instead of sh:

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | zsh
```

After adding the variables to your .zshrc file, restart your terminal or call `source ~/.zshrc` to pull the new .zshrc changes into your terminal session. Deno should work after that.